# How to get Last Record from Oracle without using RowID?

Tags: oracle

I have 1 column table which is following:

```
Time_Minutes
6.950
6.967
6.083
```

I am getting these value after writing 2 pages big query in Oracle. From this, I want last record which is 6.083

But the issue is, I can not use ROWID as I am using order by and distinct in big query. What are other approaches?

Also, I can not use Order By Logic.

Comment: "first" and "last" are meaningless concepts without the use of an `order by`.  You say that you're using an `order by` in the query that produces these results.  Do you want to use that query's `order by` to determine "first" and "last"?

Comment: You could use `row_number() over (partition by a order by b)` to generate a custom row number that you can later use to only select a certain window. Provide us with more details please.

Comment: There is no "last" row, if that information is not stored in the table. If the order the rows are inserted is important, then you need to record that as a column in the table. An Oracle `SEQUENCE` object can be used to generate an increasing integer value, and a `BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW` trigger can fetch a value from the sequence and assign the value to a column. (You are right not to use Oracle `ROWID`, that is not a reliable way to determine the order of inserts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "last record" do you mean "most recently inserted record"?

First of all, please forget the notion that ROWID would ever be useful to get this result.  Relying on ROWIDs to increase as rows are inserted into a table is asking for trouble.  Rows can be deleted and new rows inserted where the old row was.  Segments can extend and allocate extents that will have "lower" ROWID values than the previous extents.  Partitioning, row movement, any number of other features will mean that ROWIDs don't necessarily increase as new rows are inserted.

You need to have another column that tells you the order in which the rows are inserted, if that information is important to you.  Personally I would have a DATE or TIMESTAMP, which can be automatically populated with a trigger.  You could also use an ID column populated from an increasing sequence.

The only sneaky option I can think of is to use flashback versions query to figure out which row is the newest, but that would become fairly complex.

Answer (score 0):

try analytical function.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a,
            rank() over (order by a) rk, 
            count(*) over() cnt
     from tablename
    ) where rk = ct
```

Comment: That is a horrible query only useful if the original question is part of an aptitude test or homework assignment. Query plan will be subpar. I am not saying that the answer is wrong, not even that there is a better answer given the conditions from the OP. However, going after the why's of some of those conditions, might reveal the actual issue.

Comment: Since you're ranking by `a`, and then taking the last row, how is this different from simply selecting `MAX(a)`?

Comment: @joD, my intention was to just let him know that he can use analytical function if he doesn't want to use rowid/rownum. After looking at Dave's answer I think I didn't understand the question properly.

Comment: @Dave, Yes Max will work to get the last one., but with rank check we can get any record..thanks